# loading images from MediaStore fails with Picasso on android 7.1

Tags: android, picasso

Hi I am loading images to grid from android MediaStore like  this

```
   private ArrayList<ImageItem> loadImageData() {
    Cursor cursor;
    int columnIndex;

    // Set up an array of the Thumbnail Image ID column we want
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA};

    // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard

    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, // Which columns to return
            null,       // Return all rows
            null,
            null);
    // Get the column index of the Thumbnails Image ID
    int imageID;

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
        imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
        int nameIndex = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int fullImageIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        String uri = "file://" + cursor.getString(fullImageIndex);


        int thumbIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA);
        String TbUri = "file://" + cursor.getString(thumbIndex);



        imageItems.add(new ImageItem(TbUri, cursor.getString(nameIndex), uri));
        cursor.moveToNext();
        }

    cursor.close();
    return imageItems;
}
```

then I add the thumbs to grid

```
     Picasso.with(gridContext).load(item.getImage()).fit().centerCrop().into(Holder.image);
```

on on android  4.0.1  device this  code works  fine.

but on android 7.1  I get few images loaded to grid an rest are missing.
images that don't show are JPEG taken with  the device camera. images  from download folder or whatsApp are shown correctly.

In logcat I get error below:

`e: Invalid image: ExifInterface got an unsupported image format file(ExifInterface supports JPEG and some RAW image formats only) or a corrupted JPEG file to ExifInterface.                                                                   java.io.IOException: Invalid marker: 89`

could this be related to thumbnails? because I use:

```
 int thumbIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA);
    String TbUri = "file://" + cursor.getString(thumbIndex);
```

Comment: id didn't help to change  it to MediaStore.Images.DATA

Comment: seems to be related to picasso.  Because ImageView.setImageUri(() straight Without Picasso  it works.  But Ofcourse  uses too much resources that's why I used  picasso in  first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

downgrading to Picasso version 2.4.0 seems to fix the issue. Might be device related too. My device is onePlus 3 7.1.1   hope  this helps someone else.